# ActiveAdmin default_actions cause route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am trying to create a basic ActiveAdmin app to handle the content of a MySQL table. The view works fine, as does the New Store Group button and form. However, when I try to add `default_actions` for basic CRUD I get a routing error. Any idea why this happens?

My register code under app/admin/:

```
ActiveAdmin.register StoreGroup do
index do                            
  column "Group ID", :GRP_ID                     
  column "Group Name", :GRP_NM        
  column "Location Number", :LOC_NBR           
end                                 

filter :GRP_NM, :label => "Group Name"                       
filter :LOC_NBR, :label => "Location Number"                       

form do |f|                         
  f.inputs "Store Group Details" do       
    f.input :GRP_ID, :label => "Group ID"                  
    f.input :GRP_NM, :label => "Group Name"               
    f.input :LOC_NBR, :label => "Location Number"  
  end                               
  f.actions                         
end                                 
end
```

That much works fine. When I add `default_actions` under `column "Location Number", :LOC_NBR` I get for following error when I navigate to the page:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/store_groups", :id=>#<StoreGroup GRP_ID: 10, GRP_NM: "Damien", LOC_NBR: "99999">}
```

That is a valid object in my database, and displays just fine when default_actions is not present.

For reference, here is my model:

```
class StoreGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "zeus_#{Rails.env}"
  set_table_name "str_grp"

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :GRP_ID, :GRP_NM, :LOC_NBR, :email
end
```

I am running Ruby version 1.9.3p385 and Rails 3.2.12.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like your model doesn't have an `id` attribute. Does the index page work if you don't define it in the register?

Comment: Try calling `set_primary_key :GRP_ID` in your `StoreGroup` model and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks guys - this was for work and the team decided to go a different route (haha) so I'm not working on this any longer. Thanks again.